# Where to find standardized NGSI-LD entity types and their attributes

Tags: fiware

I'm getting up to speed on NGSI-LD and looking for the list of predefined entity types and their attributes. https://schema.lab.fiware.org/ld/context.jsonld has a list of names and URI's but I'm not sure what these represent.

The spec from ETSI GS CIM 009 V1.2.2 (2020-02) defines entity type but not where they are to be found. For interoperability this seems to be rather important.

As an example, trying to answer the question: what is the entity type for a temperature sensor and what attributes should it contain?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

UPDATE: trying to be a bit more specific
The NGSI spec 'CIM009v010202 page 18' defines an entity type as follows:

> "NGSI-LD Entity Type: categorization of an NGSI-LD Entity as belonging
> to a class of similar entities, or sharing a set of characteristic
> properties"

The FiWare [broker API](https://forge.etsi.org/swagger/ui/?url=https://forge.etsi.org/gitlab/NGSI-LD/NGSI-LD/raw/master/spec/updated/full_api.json#/) has a query function through which you can query entities using the entity type. The entity type is a mandatory property of the entity.

As a consumer in order to query for entities the entity type must be known. To be effective, all producers and consumers must use the same entity type definitions. In addition if two producers use the same entity type you would expect that they also use the same entity attributes in order to be interoperable with consumers.

In short, as a developer of an IoT agent, or a consumer of IoT data I need to know what entity type to expect for queries and what attributes it contains for using its data.
There are some examples  in the [ngsi-ld data models howto](https://fiware.github.io/data-models/specs/ngsi-ld_howto.html) that contain entity type and attributes. The question is whether there is a authoritative list that developers can use.

Comment: There is nothing special about `https://schema.lab.fiware.org/ld/context.jsonld` , it is merely an aggregation of the **Linked Data** attributes from the [FIWARE Data Models](https://fiware-datamodels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). 

This has been expanded with a wider range of contributors into the [Smart Data Models Initiative](https://www.fiware.org/developers/smart-data-models/)

Comment: The FIWARE tutorials [here](https://ngsi-ld-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and  [here](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/linked-data/index.html) good place to start (particularly the JSON-LD Videos). The NGSI-LD tutorials state you should host and share your own `@context`.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I'll check it out.